# Regex in Ruby to capture message

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I achieve something like this:

```
listen_for /say (REGEX_THAT_CAPTURES_EVERYTHING_AFTER_SAY)/i do |message|
    puts "Message: #{message}"
end
```

With what do I have to replace `(REGEX_THAT_CAPTURES_EVERYTHING_AFTER_SAY)` so that everything after `say` is captured:

Input

```
say Hello there
```

Result

```
Message: Hello there
```

Comment: While I realize that SO is convenient, it probably wouldn't hurt to learn some basic regex.

Comment: Of course it would not hurt, however, with regex I ALWAYS seem to forget it again, because I don't seem to use it often enough. I know it is quite a simple example, but not necessarily one that is also easy to figure if you don't know where you should look for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/say (.+)$/
```

maybe?